# LoadRunner TruClient - Power BI module shows 'Navigation to the webpage was canceled.'

Tags: powerbi, loadrunner, truclient

I have a page with Power BI report module. When I reply my scenario in LoadRunner TruClient (IE), it shows 'Navigation to the webpage was canceled'. But if I launch the page in IE, it is shown fine. Anybody can tell me why this is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loadrunner's Truclient (IE) protocol uses its own engine and is not at all like a real IE browser. It has vast differences and compatibility issues. I suggest writing all scripts in TruClient **Firefox** protocol, which uses a 100% real Firefox browser.